# how include activiti.cfg.xml in module project - EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, configuration, activiti

I am try include activiti engine into my project ( I would like to make new module ), but I have problem with configurtion file -> activiti.cfg.xml . I don't knew how to place in my module (jar). I put file into src/main/resources/ but when I try create default process It gives me null.
`ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();`

Do you knew how can I resolve ma problem ?

P.S. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your activiti.cfg.xml in classpath and check if problem get solved.

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine()` did find activiti.cfg.xml in classpath and initiate ProcessEngine upon configures in this file.

To find out what went wrong, you should:

- Make sure you have put activiti.cfg.xml in classpath. In your scenario, you may check the Jar, whether activiti.cfg.xml is under the root of Jar file.
- Make sure you have a correct activiti.cfg.xml. When running `ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine()`, look up the console or log files, to see if there are any exceptions or errors.